# Populate dataframe by unnesting list of the first column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, delimiter

I have the following issue with a csv in panda the data looks as follow :

```
Column A :row1: [« a », « b »; « c »
Row2 : [« d »; « e », « f »
```

Etc …
Note the different delimiters.

I would like it to populate next column based on the cell keys in the list in it like this :

```
ColA row 1: [a] col b:[b] colc[c]
   Row 2: [d] col b:[e] colc:[f]
```

And so on for as many values there is in a cell I would like it to populate over every column it’s row.

I hope to get some insights from you and that my explanation is clear,

Thanks

Im struggling so far

I can’t share the data but basically I have every row in column A that contains a list csv like with separators and I would like for n number of values within this list in this cell to populate n number of rows in the next columns. , I think I would need to strip the data based on the multiple delimiters and treat them as one ( as you would do in excel ) and then for each row create a function appending each values of the first cell list ? But I’m not sure how to create this…

Each « Keys » of the list in the cell with separated values should go to a the next row (horizontal) in the next column and this for each rows in the data set I would like to un-nest these strings

Comment: Please write your examples more clearly.

Comment: Provide the output of `df.head().to_dict()` assuming `df` is your DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your `I/O` but you can try this :

```
import pandas as pd

df= (
        pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep="[;,]", engine="python",
                    header=None, skiprows=1)
            .astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip("« »"))
    )

# convert the numeric index columns to alphabetic letters
df.columns= (
                df.columns.astype(str)
                    .str.replace(r"(\d)", 
                                 lambda m: "Col" + chr(ord('@')+ int(float(m.group(0)))+1),
                                 regex=True)
            )
```

##### # Output:

```
print(df)

  ColA ColB ColC
0    a    b    c
1    d    e    f
```

##### # .txt used:

[image]